# What happens if in a random access file the file pointer offset exceeds the long datatype capability

Tags: java, undefined-behavior, randomaccessfile

What would the following code do in case I have a file that has more than 2^63-1 bytes?

```
RandomAccesFile raf = new RandomAccesFile (new File("path"), "rw");
long x = raf.length(); //I expect this will throw some exception
```

or

```
RandomAccesFile raf = new RandomAccesFile (new File("path"), "rw");
raf.seek(Long.MAX_VALUE);
raf.read(); 
raf.read();
raf.read();//I expect this will work
```

Comment: Can you imagine HOW BIG is that number???

Comment: I don't think any file system supports big enough files.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect this will throw some exception

It will probably truncate the file length to 64 bits. But you won't live long enough to see a file this big.

> raf.read();//I expect this will work

It will either:

1. work
2. return -1, or
3. thrown a exception, depending on how long the file is and whether the I/O completed successfully.

   Without inspecting the return value you will be unable to distinguish 1 and 2.